# Map array of keys to an object without using index

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create an object with keys as parameters and value as value returned by `getParameter()`.

Is there a more secure way of mapping the values rather than by using the index? I'm not too confident this is safe.

```
enum Parameter {
  ENABLE_NEW_UI: 'ENABLE_NEW_UI',
  ENABLE_TEST_FEATURES: 'ENABLE_TEST_FEATURES',
}

type ParametersResponse = Partial<Record<Parameter, string | number | boolean>>;

const getParameters = (): Promise<ParametersResponse> => {
  const parameters = [Parameter.ENABLE_NEW_UI];

  const parametersResponse = await Promise.all<Promise<string | number | boolean>[]>(
    parameters.map(parameter => getParameter(parameter)),
  );

  return parametersResponse.reduce((previous, current, index) => {
    // Don't feel too confident about [parameters[index]]
    return { ...previous, [parameters[index]]: current };
  }, {});
};
```

**Expected output:**

```
{
  ENABLE_NEW_UI: true,
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBACghgJzhYAXYCoG8BQV9QCiAcgIIBCAMoQPrGEDqNAqgJJQC8UA5CRdXUYtW3ADR4CfKrQAqhAMoyaAMUKkZzAEoLOPKQLmKVajdvlicAXxw4AxgHsQAZ1RQADomRoMTzWjAIIMAAJuQAnspwANbAfk5ujk7AAFxQfg4IwQA88Ego6AiiUC4IAJYgAOZQAD5Q4BAARhg1UA329gA2wHAgAHy6uARQANq5XgUAdPq09ExsALqpqAhgwOJDo575GFNk0jSGSqrqWgqLUABmcB1J4tZ2ia4VaGPbmFxwTmEgtlAAFB48t4EKlXsCAJSghD2CClJJZErlKq1epNTC1Nqdbp9Tj9QYEBD%20QJQOAAdzgpVcQVJsGhsKSfz%20hKcnQAbsBwbjsBIhvgkqgZKUUPYwKhGZyOHiebyhsy2cAAVtgb4iUFQhForFgPFEsBNkDJtNBHNWPNwdKhpYigBWAAMtvBAG5pZZzdYhjZUGE3MBYEqCiqdc5fVxcqhStcsul7Jkcv6MEVEZUWqjmhj2l0er1es6Hs4ni94wgnLpPt9fn9IbSYXDgHGDT44glg-1Jdyhg58%204iyWuPrxjsjbNhPNcx3Ht2G8Wm7rS%20TKdX6cAJtcOjk6bWEcskSnIGiWpjM31hvNen8LQRAQPixMIHA3Iqp1znqgwQVH9fweD1gQnTZZaqk7XoGzZJBMhLBGAtgKgChKsqUIpOEUtgBISICoEU5TBMAAAeEpSjK%20AAPREVAAAijjcK4FzAMAHRQKg7RQJ2FylNh6Ekm0oojFebxOMMWG4fM8wXvghKoAEIDYFAEyyW4cEIWASE8T2AkgNhOHCakKEIGhriWM6lpFFgrrOgZNh-GWPz-Ph7YEJ2LJdBMHT2BUfzcC%20b4%20GIJLzgWr49pWf6upWjpAA)

Comment: _"Is there a more secure way..."_, _"I'm not too confident this is safe."_ - Why? And "safe" in what way?

Comment: @Andreas a more bug proof way I believe. I want to be sure that the parameter is always going to have its matching key in the object. Right now I am not so sure that index gives me the confidence.

Comment: Then test it first. You can do anything you want in the `.reduce()` callback

Comment: I did, I'm searching for better way if there is one.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/m0yoOW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: The code in the question works but is vulnerable to the arrays possibly being of different length. This might cause issue with mapping using `index`. I've added TS playground link to the question.